# How to do left join in Azure Cosmos DB using gremlin API

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Im studying Gremlin API of Azure Cosmos DB and im trying to translate some SQL statements to Gremlin traversals.

Commands below:

```
//add product vertex
g.addV('product').property('id', 'product1')
g.addV('product').property('id', 'product2')
g.addV('product').property('id', 'product3')
g.addV('product').property('id', 'product4')
g.addV('product').property('id', 'product5')

//add product_category vertex
g.addV('product_category').property('id', 'category1')
g.addV('product_category').property('id', 'category2')

//connect product and product_categories

g.V('product1').addE('belongs_to').to(g.V('category1'))
g.V('product2').addE('belongs_to').to(g.V('category1'))
g.V('product3').addE('belongs_to').to(g.V('category2'))
g.V('product4').addE('belongs_to').to(g.V('category2'))
g.V('product5').addE('belongs_to').to(g.V('category2'))

//add image vertex
g.addV('image').property('public_url', 'url_1').property('id', 'image1')
g.addV('image').property('public_url', 'url_2').property('id', 'image2')


//link products to images

g.V('product1').addE('belongs_to').property('primary', true).to(g.V('image1'))
g.V('product2').addE('belongs_to').property('primary', true).to(g.V('image2'))
```

Now as you can see not all products have images.

I want to be able to select all the products with category and image property.
If a product doesnt have an image, it should still be selected with a null image property.

Im trying to do something similar to left join by following this link:
http://sql2gremlin.com/#_left_join

But unfortunately Gremlin API of Azure Cosmos does not yet support match() step.

My current query only selects products that have outgoing edge to image:

```
g.V()
.has('label', 'product')
.as('product')
.outE('has_image')
.has('primary', true)
.inV()
.as('primary_image')
.in('has_image')
.out('belongs_to')
.as('category')
.select('product','primary_image','category')
.by(__.valueMap()).by(__.values('public_url')).by(__.values('name'))
```

Comment: an example would be very useful to improve the quality of the question. Show us a sample of the kind the data you have, the edges and vertices you have and the traversal you are trying to run.

Comment: Thank you for your correction, Please see the editted version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a couple of things going on here:

1) The script you had above didn't work correctly to insert the data into a TinkerGraph (I don't have a Cosmos account).  I have added the updated script below.

2) What you are trying to doesn't need a left join.  Since these are both relationships off the product you can just project your results from the product vertices as shown here:

```
g.V().
  hasLabel('product').
  project('product', 'category', 'image').
    by(id()).
    by(out('belongs_to').id()).
    by(
      __.out('has_image').fold().
      coalesce(
        unfold().id(), 
        constant('No Image')
      )
    )
```

This works by finding all product vertices and then returning the image and category

3) The coalesce statement there is based on [this](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.4/recipes/#element-existence) Gremlin recipe to check for element existence.  If it does not find anything, because a recipe doesn't exist it returns a constant value

4) Gremlin doesn't allow for returning a `null` values so you need to return something

Updated Add Script

```
//add product vertex
g.addV('product').property(id, 'product1')
g.addV('product').property(id, 'product2')
g.addV('product').property(id, 'product3')
g.addV('product').property(id, 'product4')
g.addV('product').property(id, 'product5')

//add product_category vertex
g.addV('product_category').property(id, 'category1')
g.addV('product_category').property(id, 'category2')

//connect product and product_categories

g.V('product1').addE('belongs_to').to(g.V('category1'))
g.V('product2').addE('belongs_to').to(g.V('category1'))
g.V('product3').addE('belongs_to').to(g.V('category2'))
g.V('product4').addE('belongs_to').to(g.V('category2'))
g.V('product5').addE('belongs_to').to(g.V('category2'))

//add image vertex
g.addV('image').property(id, 'image1').property('public_url', 'url_1')
g.addV('image').property(id, 'image2').property('public_url', 'url_2')


//link products to images

g.V('product1').addE('has_image').to(V('image1')).property('primary', true)
g.V('product2').addE('has_image').to(V('image2')).property('primary', true)
```